# Loading generic type works in simulator but not device

Tags: ios, generics, xamarin.ios

In my iOS app, I've got a custom UIView that displays a list of values listed in an Enum.  This is generic, so the same class can work with any Enum:

```
public class EnumViewer<TEnumType> : UIView
{...}
```

Suppose I have, say, a color:

```
public enum Color
{
  Red,
  Green,
  Blue
}
```

I can view these values in the app using the view like so:

```
var view = new EnumViewer<Color>
//add to parent view, set the frame, etc.
```

The point, of course, is that I can reuse this for any Enum type. So I have an `EnumViewer<ThisSet>` and an `EnumViewer<ThatSet>`, and a `Choose This` button and a `Choose That` button.  If you click one of the buttons, it shows the list of choices from the appropriate enum in a popup.

This works perfectly on the simulator.  The very weird problem is that on the device, and **NOT** in the simulator, the app gets confused and shows the list for the **WRONG** enum.  To be precise, if you click `Choose This`, it'll show the list of `ThisSet` items, but if you then click `Choose That`, it shows the same list.  And if you click `Choose That` **FIRST**, it DOES correctly show the list of `ThatSet` items, but then if you click `Choose This`, it again shows the list of `ThatSet` values.  I have verified that it's actually creating the view each time, but `TEnumType` is actually wrong, and I can't figure out why.  I know the code is correct because it works fine in the simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xamarin.iOS does not support generic classes that subclass a native class.   This was turning into an error or a warning recently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but boy I wish it had remained an error, because I didn't notice the warning until after I had build a major subsystem that depends on a generic subtype of UIView.  If this behavior is so unreliable on the device, shouldn't the compiler firmly prevent you from doing it?

Comment: So now my question is how to redesign my app.  My best idea is to replace the generic type with a simple System.Type variable, which identifies a generic factory class (not derived from NSObject), set the factory class type at runtime, and have the factory class do the generic functionality that I wanted the view to do.  Or can you offer a better suggestion.  And, is *this* going to be a safe thing to do?  Are generics fine in regular C# objects?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank: The reason it's not an error is because we didn't detect the situation for a very long time, and now there are many apps that happen to work fine in spite of this problem, and making it an error would break those apps (iow a strange case of backwards compatibility). And yes, generics are fine in regular C# objects.

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge: Thanks for the explanation.  Indeed, I made a silly change to my app, leaving the architecture as is, and now it does work fine.  Specifically, I can use EnumViewer<TEnumType> just fine, but if I define class MyEnumViewer : EnumViewer<MyEnum>, and then try to use MyEnumViewer, it doesn't work.  I was only doing this to save typing, so I can live with that.  But do you have **any** idea why that specific code would be a problem?  Is there any documentation about what might be done to guarantee safe code using generics (i.e. info about linking so we know how to avoid trouble)?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank: you should not use generics with any NSObject subclass, you can end up with truly random behavior (such as crashing because you're in a leap year for instance). The fact that it apparently works doesn't mean it won't fail somehow later.

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge: I figured that would be the advice.  Do you have a link to an article that explains exactly what's going on here?  I've seen a bunch of advice not to do it, but not what the underlying reason is.  Had I known, I wouldn't have done it this way, and now I need some time to redesign things.  Luckily, no leap years coming soon.  :-)

Comment: @JoshuaFrank: unfortunately we do not have an article explaining the underlying issue. It is a fairly complex topic (a generics implementation is by itself quite complex, and now try to explain it in code so that the ObjC runtime can understand it...) However we are working on fixing some scenarios, but we don't have a timeline yet for this.